# Access keys in dictionary by object string representation instead of object

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which is keyed by tuples of objects of a specific class:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label

obj1 = MyClass('obj1')
obj2 = MyClass('obj2')
obj3 = MyClass('obj3')
obj4 = MyClass('obj4')

my_dict = {(obj1, obj2): 'foo', (obj3, obj4): 'bar'}

print(my_dict[(obj1, obj2)])

# this should also be possible (string API for dict): 
# print(my_dict[('obj1', 'obj2')])
# which works with the following code but seems to be not the best solution
my_dict2 = {tuple([str(e) for e in k]): v for k, v in my_dict.items()}
print(my_dict2[('obj1', 'obj2')])
```

Now I want to provide the possibility to access elements by using keys with object string representations e.g. `my_dict[('obj1', 'obj2')` and I am not sure about how to solve this in a clean and efficient way.

My first and probably obvious idea was to convert all keys to strings e.g. `('obj1','obj2')` within another dictionary.

But isn't there a more elegant way to provide both access options (keys=objects/strings) on the same dict like overriding the dictionary class and providing additional methods or writing some sort wrapper function? What would be a good way to solve this?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Making your object a subclass of `str` would do the job.  Your label would become the underlying value of the object, rather than a field of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, `MyClass` is already derived from another base class and this cannot be changed :(